# Can I make a game on html JavaScript without a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I am planning to make a game of flappy birds which will accept values (up, down) from a textfield instead of a mouse click. Can I make such animations of my bird moving without a canvas?
I am trying to display my images on the canvas with some animations but they won't display.

Comment: It's not impossible. css `position:absolute;` and setting `top`/`left` styles.

Comment: Here on SO a question how to make your existing canvas code work would make more sense. [ask] , [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

See technology like [WebAnimations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API) to cover your goals and still use GPU acceleration when available.  Also, you can create graphics and animation with scalable vector graphics aka [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Introduction).